# Error trying to deploy or run a MAUI Blazor project

Tags: maui, maui-blazor

I'm trying to deploy then run a default MAUI Blazor application, but when I try to deploy and when I try to run it, I receive the same error: "Cannot resolve metadadata forWinUI types. Please ensure that NuGet Restore was successful."

However I have no idea how to fix it and couldn't find its fix on the internet.

Comment: Have you tried to check on the different platform configurations in the csproj ?

Comment: @Jean yes i did, nothing changed.

Comment: What platform did you try it on ?

Comment: if this helps, you may try this sample (windows only) https://github.com/JeanCollas/MauiBlazorDependencyInjection
Also your templates might be outdated ?